# Change in a Balde Template caused a problem in a business Logic in a Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-10

Can a Change in UI affect business logic in a controller?
well, the answer should be a big NO

but here's what made me suspect this fact.

I am using an anchor element inside a table cell to delete a record from a data base and then refresh the page with the remaining records after deletion

```php
                <table id="datatablesSimple">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Created on</th>
                            <th>Edit</th>
                            <th>Delete</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach ($jobs as $job)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $job->title }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $job->created_at->format('Y-m-d') }}</td>
                                <td><a href="{{ route('job.edit', [$job]) }}">Edit</a></td>
                                <td><a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#id{{$job->id}}">Delete</a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <form action="{{ route('job.delete', [$job->id]) }}" method="POST">
                                @csrf
                                @method('delete')
                                <!-- Modal -->
                                <div class="modal fade" id="id{{$job->id}}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Delete Confirmation</h1>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                Are you sure you want to delete this job?
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        @endforeach

                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

The delete anchor element should trigger a modal that make user confirm the deletion

The problem is that the delete button in the modal doesn't work when pressed without showing any error

Here is route:

```php
Route::delete('/job/{id}/delete', [JobPostController::class, 'delete'])->name('job.delete');
```

here the `delete` method in `JobPostController` class;

```php
    public function delete($id){
        Listing::find($id)->delete();
        return back()->with('successMessage', 'Your job post has been deleted successfully');
    }
```

The weird part is the following:

When I add a `td` element (which will invalidate the document) it works perfectly

```php
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $job->title }}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{ $job->created_at->format('Y-m-d') }}</td>
        <td><a href="{{ route('job.edit', [$job]) }}">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#id{{$job->id}}">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
```

Iam using Laravel 10.x with XAMP on Chrome and Windows 11

Any Ideas about what is going on ????

I eard the docs but without find any ideas

Comment: fyi, `<form>` inside a `<tbody>` is invalid

Comment: Step 1 would be to check if the form is actually being submitted; step 2 would be to look at the actual HTML being generated, not your blade template; and step 3 is checking the browser inspector to make sure it's not being broken somehow (like by having a form inside a tbody)